# DynamoDB and Unit Testing .NET core

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, mocking, amazon-dynamodb

We are implementing DynamoDB data store. For our unit tests we have got that covered for Web.API, services, repository layers. However, I have not found any mocking frameworks/unit test for DynamoDB for .NET Core, only to implement the local DynamoDB (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-dynamodb-libraries-mappers-and-mock-implementations-galore/) Amazon indicates that it's best to run the local instance (Dynamo Local), however, this is not ideal for us, since we have Azure dev-ops pipelines in place. This causes other issues,like deleting tables for each test run, making sure the local db instance is running etc.

I was thinking of extending the DynamoDBclient, DynamoContext etc and then use these to simulate, however, this seems like a lot of work and I am not sure if it is worthwhile. Can anyone suggest an easier alternative or have come across a framework, or implemented a good unit testing framework for DynamoDB for .NET Core. We really don't want to go down the path to use the local DynamoDB on our build server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52784546/net-core-dynamoddb-unit-testing-with-xunit)

Comment: My understanding, from what the documentation indicates, It's probably best to create a DynamoDB in AWS and reference it there. Also, provides integration testing as well. We have implemented a CloudFormation stack which creates the DynamoDB for each deployment in this case for CI. Just thought I would add my experience here if anyone else has this same issue.